# Does JSch support SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: java, curl, ssh, jsch, socks

I am trying to connect my Java application via a SOCKS5 proxy to an SFTP Server with the library [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

My local DNS does not resolve the hostname. Therefor the lookup should be done on the Socks Proxy.

In cURL that is possible via socks5h or [`--socks5-hostname`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--socks5-hostname) parameter.

Is that option available in JSch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [`Session.setProxy`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setProxy-com.jcraft.jsch.Proxy-) to set [`ProxySOCKS5`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ProxySOCKS5.html) proxy:

```
ProxySOCKS5 proxy = new ProxySOCKS5(proxy_host, proxy_port);
session.setProxy(proxy);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to use `-DsocksProxyHost=proxy_host -DsocksProxyPort=proxy_port` as JVM options? The advantage of this approach would be not having to change the code and redeploy the applications